# JavaScript replace all

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to write some JavaScript code to replace characters in a variable:

```
var data = "abcd.-3*(adsa3sd"
```

From the variable `data` I have to replace `0-9a-zA-Z` and `.` characters.

I want the output to be:

```
-*(
```

How can it be done?

Comment: have you tried google first? http://naspinski.net/post/Javascript-replaceAll-function.aspx

Comment: you only need a new regex for this

Comment: yes i did tried, but all results says about a continous string only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short version:

```
"abcd.-3*(adsa3sd".replace( /[\da-zA-Z.]+/g, '' );
>> "-*("
```

Comment: You could also quantify the `[]` with a `+` to reduce the number of replacements necessary.

Comment: @MikeM You're right. On the other side, I guess that JS engines optimize such things. This is a nice idea for research.

Comment: @MikeM [Test case confirmed](http://jsperf.com/replace-and-quantifiers). You're right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`text.replace(new RegExp('[A-Z|a-z|0-9|\\.]','g'),"")` to get rid of that .

Comment: or you could directly use `text.replace(new RegExp('[A-Z|a-z|0-9]','g'),"")`

Comment: @SantoshPingale The output is `.-*(`, not `-*(`.

Comment: Then use `text.replace(new RegExp('[A-Z|a-z|0-9|\.]','g'),"")` to get rid of that .

Comment: @SantoshPingale There's no need for `|` inside of `[]`. This is how `[]` works ;)

Comment: Ohhh I forgot. It has been a while since I last touched regex for my bread and butter.

Comment: to whom got me a -1 please explain

Answer (score -1):

Use `text.replace(new RegExp('[A-Z|a-z|0-9|\.]','g'),"")` where `text` is the string object.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but I would assume it was because you used new RegExp vs a literal.

Comment: Use of regex literal internally calls `new RegExp()` and I believe if the same literal is encountered multiple times in a js, multiple instances of RegExp will be created. So i am curious about what difference does it make? Maybe my understanding about this concept is wrong.